# How to convert a plain txt file to json format

Tags: conversion, json, plaintext

I have a huge plain txt file which its content is:

```
p1=a05b518f35e9f55a37d27965f3bf8735|p2=dabfa1619199d358d5ee7a38768a564a|p3=...
```

I want to convert it to JSON format with a **p***n*-**hash** pair. I found this URL: https://www.vertopal.com/en/document/convert/txt-to-json

But when I click the convert button and download the JSON file, the result is not what I'm expected:

```
{"p1": null}
```

Any helps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Click on the "delimiter" and use custom delimiters

change the ";" in pair delimiter to "|"

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I missed that option on the page.